# Entries in suspect_pages but checkdb shows no error

Tags: sql-server-2016, corruption

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 23:15:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Yesterday, I got two entries in "suspect_pages" for the same database. One of event type 1 and one of type 2

> 1 = An 823 error that causes a suspect page (such as a disk error) or an 824 error other than a bad checksum or a torn page (such as a bad page ID).
>
> 2 = Bad checksum.

```
database_id file_id page_id eventtype   error_count last_update_date
8           1       1482057 1           1           2019-11-14 14:40
8           1       1482057 2           1           2019-11-14 14:40
```

I found the object related and they both point to the same table on the database.

`DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC PAGE (8, 1, 14823057, 0);
DBCC TRACEOFF (3604);`

I had a valid backup of before the corruption and couldn't afford a down time so I took a backup of the corrupted database, restored my backup on a new name. I dropped the corrupted table and then recreated it from the valid backup.

Today, I restored the corrupted database backup that I took yesterday on a test server and when I run a full checkdb, it detects no corruption.

> DBCC CheckDB() WITH No_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS

How is it possible that the backup I took from a corrupted database (according to suspect_pages) doesn't have any problems? Can those entries in suspect_pages be a false positive?

Database Compatibility Level is 130 (SQL 2016) Our SQL Server is running on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: can you post the event_type as well `repaired, restored, or deallocated` - `5,4 or 7` ? That will explain why you get a clean checkdb.

Comment: event_type is 1 and 2, I'll correct my question so that it's easier to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wrote to Brent Ozar and this is the answer I got from him. It's the best answer I've got so far so I'll put it here:

> here's exactly what I do when SQL Server reports corruption:
>   https://brentozar.com/go/corruption
>
> Suspect_pages doesn't do false positives, but the corruption may have been repaired since (or may have only been corrupt temporarily, like if storage had a transient error when you went to go read it the first time.) Definitely follow that checklist and star tthe support call with MS.
>
> Hope that helps!
>   Brent